# How can I make this program display a counter a different way?

Tags: java, swing

So I understand how to make it so when a user presses a button, the count goes up, but how would I make it so it displays the amount of times the button has been pressed in a different way. For example, if the user pressed the button 3 times, it would say 123, instead of 3.

This is my current method with does it a conventional way,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            count++;
            label.setText("Pushes: " + count);

    }
```

So I'm thinking maybe I can make it so it loops through each posted value and displays that?

Comment: take a String btnpress=""+count; label.setText("Pushes:"+btnpress);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialise `countStr` globally, than on the button click append the count with `StringBuilder` like:

```
StringBuilder countStr= new StringBuilder();
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
 count++
 countStr.append(count);
 label.setText("Pushes: " +countStr);
}
```

Comment: OHHHH. This makes so much sense, totally forgot about the append. Thanks!